# strpos cannot find apostrophe?

Tags: php, strpos

I have a piece of PHP code that is baffling me when I test it:

```
$found = $found + (int)(strpos($entry,"'"));   // apostrophe
```

when I test with this string in the variable $entry:

```
'b29vF@XsJ
```

the function should find the apostrophe and increment `$found`

UNLESS I am mistaken, and the position of this apostrophe is position ZERO?

Just thought of that, let me know if that is why that is happening. Because that would explain my issue and I'll code it differently.

And thanks!

Comment: Yes, the index is zero.

Comment: Yep, `false` means didn't find, `0` means found as first character. Use `===` to tell the difference.

Comment: Relevant documentation section: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues

Comment: Can you show an example of using === to tell the difference?  And thanks all!

Comment: Sure. Are you trying to increment `$found` by 1, or by the index where the apostrophe was found?

Comment: The docs page that @Don'tPanic has linked shows an example

Comment: Thanks, everyone! Problem solved.  

The reason this confusion happened is because I typically use Vbscript in ASP, and the vbscript function InStr.  

InStr returns the position as 1 for the first position, not zero.  So you see the nature of my confusion.     

:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if it's at the begging then it's index is 0. So:

```
$found = $found + 0
```

You might try something like:

```
$found = strpos($entry,"'") === false ?: $found + 1;
```

Or:

```
if (strpos($entry,"'") !== false) {
    $found += 1;
}
```

Comment: If the goal is to increment by 1, `$found += strpos($entry,"'") !== false;` is pretty straightforward too, but I wasn't sure if that was what they were going for or not.

Comment: I though so as well. BTW. it's a nice snippet to test familiarity with php's type casting.